# Duplicate @AuraEnabled methods in 2 separate Apex Controllers, is it really code duplication?

Tags: class, aura, wrapper-class

so recently our code sniffer flagged 2 methods in 2 of our Apex controllers as "duplicated code" and I'm wondering if this is a false positive in this case, see example below.
Both getRecords() methods do look the same, but each is using a different inner class wrapper in the return statement.
Controller 1:

```
public with sharing class Controller1 {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<CustomInnerClass> getRecords(){
        List<CustomInnerClass> customList = new List<CustomInnerClass>();
        ...(populate customList with CustomInnerClass instances)...
        return customList;
    }

    public class CustomInnerClass{

        @AuraEnabled public DateTime activityDate;
        @AuraEnabled public String activityType;
        @AuraEnabled public Id recordId;
        @AuraEnabled public String recordTypeFullName;

    public CustomInnerClass( Id x ){
        this.recordId = x;
        this.activityDate = ...;
        this.activityType = ...;
        this.recordTypeFullName = ...;
        }
    }
}
```

And the second one is:

```
public with sharing class Controller2 {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<CustomInnerClass> getRecords(){
        List<CustomInnerClass> customList = new List<CustomInnerClass>();
        ...(populate customList with CustomInnerClass instances)...
        return customList;
    }

    public class CustomInnerClass{

        @AuraEnabled public String activityDescription;
        @AuraEnabled public String activityTypeLabel;
        @AuraEnabled public Id recordId;

    public CustomInnerClass( Id x ){
        this.recordId = x;
        this.activityDescription = ...;
        this.activityTypeLabel = ...;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a valid case or duplicate code that should be extracted into a separate class?
If the latter how would I reference the inner classes with their constructors?
Any practical architectural advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: which code sniffer do you use? would like to look into it for my team

Comment: it's the SonarQube Apex scan, runs on each commit in the ci/cd pipeline, its typically ran before merging the feature branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to provide the value while instantiating the class's object?
If the process of extracting the value and data processing is similar then you can use the following:

```
public with sharing class Controller1 {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<CustomInnerClass> getRecords(){
    
    CustomInnerClass customInnerClass1 = new customInnerClass1();
    
    //Provide the values of customInnerClass1 as per your requirement
    List<CustomInnerClass> customList = new List<CustomInnerClass>();
    ...(populate customList with CustomInnerClass instances)...
    return customList;
}
public class CustomInnerClass{
    
    //Variables of first inner class
    @AuraEnabled public DateTime activityDate;
    @AuraEnabled public String activityType;
    @AuraEnabled public Id recordId;
    @AuraEnabled public String recordTypeFullName;
    
    //Variables from second Inner class
    @AuraEnabled public String activityDescription;
    @AuraEnabled public String activityTypeLabel;
}
```

}

Comment: thanks, that's almost what I did, I was first worried about refactoring someone's code, but introducing a service class and referencing the inner class and method from there seems to solved the issue